# Is there a way of getting ngrams from tuples?

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, nltk

I am working with a corpus tagged for dependencies. Each word of the corpus is a tuple containing 5 elements: the position of the word in the sentence, the actual word, the POS, the index of the word it depends on and the function. From this corpus I want to convert those tags and relations to another according to some rules. To write these rules I want to start by getting the corpus in bigrams.

I was trying to use nltk ngrams function as showed in the code below. However, as I am working with tuples it does not work and what I get is the whole corpus back with apparently no bigrams divided.

I was trying to use nltk ngrams function as showed in the code below. However, as I am working with tuples it does not work and what I get is the whole corpus back with apparently no bigrams divided.

```py
import nltk, glob 
from nltk import ngrams


def txt2corpus(path):
    """same as read_files function in corpus_opening_slicing"""
    corpus = []
    for f in glob.glob(path):
        sents1=open(f).read().split('\n\n')
        sents2 = []
        for n in range(len(sents1)):
            sents2.append(sents1[n].split('\n'))
        sents3 = []
        for s in sents2:
            sent = []
            for t in s:
                sent.append(tuple(t.split('\t')))
            sents3.append(sent)
        corpus.extend(sents3)
    return corpus

corpus= txt2corpus("/Users/raquelgarnelonicolas/Desktop/80_sents_untagged.txt")

def get_ngrams(c):
    return list(ngrams(c, 2))
```

When I do ngrams(corpus) I get all the tuples for each word in the corpus, but not organised. Is there a way of getting the ngrams from these tuples? I have thought about creating a new list only with the position 1 of the tuple (the word), but I need the rest of the information in the tuple in order to write the following rules for the new tags (some rules depend on the POS of the previous word, for example). Do you guys have any idea? Thank you in advance!

Comment: So maybe you want is to have, for each word, the things you already have in its tuple _plus_ a bigram consisting of this word and the next word? Is this correct?

Comment: okay i did thought about that! adding another element to the tuple which would be the bigram can make it! thank you :D :D